# Inconsistency between XAML intellisense and compiler for a control

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, intellisense

I am converting some Silverlight XAML into WPF. I currently have a user control (`MyControl`) that is trying to include a couple of other controls that are custom buttons (`MyButton1`) that are within the same assembly. I have the following XAML that compiles and works in SL:

*MyButton1*

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="MyCompany.MyNamespace.MySubnamespace.MyButton1"
    d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">
    ...
</UserControl>
```

*MyControl*

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:somename="clr-namespace:MyCompany.MyNamespace.MySubnamespace;assembly=MyCompany.MyAssemblyName"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="MyCompany.MyNamespace.MySubnamespace.MyControl"
    d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">

    <somename:MyButton1 />

</UserControl>
```

When I try to compile this code in WPF, I get the following error:

> The tag 'MyButton1' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:MyCompany.MyNamespace.MySubnamespace;assembly=MyCompany.MyAssemblyName.'

The weird thing is, if I comment out the `<somename:MyButton1 />` line of code and compile and then type in `<somename:` IntelliSense gives me the option to autocomplete `MyButton1`. Which suggests that the control itself is in the assembly but for some reason it is not being seen when the `MyControl` XAML is being compiled.

For some context, I took the SL csproj file and made some modifications to it manually to make it a WPF csproj file. If there is a possibility that this caused this funkiness to happen, I'd be glad to share relevant portions of the project file.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious in the XAML, what do the pertinent sections of the csproj look like?  The weird discrepancy sounds like an issue that could be caused by a csproj issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on an MSDN forum. Turns out that the `assembly=MyCompany.MyAssemblyName` line in my xmlns was screwing things up. Once I removed that line, I was able to reference the controls.

Related Link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/807c9b80-81c7-4f75-aa2f-8427e17b1a90

Answer (score 1):

To reference the current assembly you must not type its name but leave it blank, i.e. `assembly=`, the other option is of course to drop it completely. ([MSDN -> Mapping to Current Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx#Mapping_To_Custom_Classes_and_Assemblies))